# How to Display image Using Session in PHP

Tags: php

i am able to display image on screen but i want to display the image using session.Please help me.

```
$_SESSION['user_name6'] = $_FILES["file"]["name"];



 if(isset($_SESSION['user_name6']))
    {
    echo "<img src=<?php echo $_SESSION[user_name6]; ?> width=300 height=400
    alt=Image path Invalid name=image />";
    }
    else
    {   
        print "no pic here";
    }
```

Comment: $_SESSION['user_name6'] = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

if(isset($_SESSION['user_name6']))
{
echo "<img src=<?php echo $_SESSION[user_name6]; ?> width=300 height=400 alt=Image path Invalid name=image />";
}
else
{

 print "no pic here";
}

Comment: Remove php from src place

Comment: You can display images like that. There are a lot more things.

Comment: You first would have to upload the pic to the db using blob or upload it to the server, then use another page to load it as image... Use that page to add in the src tag. You can't show an image by file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what you will actually do but this is the approach that best fits

when you put a file type in your form, you need to use the global variable [Files](http://php.net/manual/fr/features.file-upload.php)

**form.html**

```
 <form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="picture">Picture:</label>
  <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //make sure you have created the **upload** directory
    $filename    = $_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"];
    $destination = "upload/" . $_FILES["picture"]["name"]; 
    move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination); //save uploaded picture in your directory

    $_SESSION['user_name6'] = $destination;

    header('Location: display_picture.php');
```

**display_picture.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<div>
  <img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name6']; ?>" alt="picture"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3141880 are you checked my answer?

Comment: i am not getting image only getting image icon

Comment: where r u stored in your images.tel me image path?

Comment: one more question <?php
session_start();
?>

<?php 


@$_SESSION['name4']=$_POST['Color'];

$a=@$_SESSION['name1'];
$b=@$_SESSION['name2'];
$c=@$_SESSION['name3'];
$d=@$_SESSION['name4'];

Comment: if(($a=="Male") && ($b=='LOGO')  && ($c=='Small')  )
{

if($d=="White"  || $d=="Black") 
{

   $n=10;
   echo"".$n;

 echo"hi you selected White option";
   return false;
}
else
{
  $x=20;
  $y=20;
  $z= $x+$y;
  echo "".$z;
  
  
 echo"hi you selected other option";
 return false;
}

echo"hi you selected";
 return false;
}

?>

Comment: this is programe i am trying to add values using session in nested please help me in this also

Comment: I am not getting what you said...post this as a question.

Comment: this is second question

Comment: i tried  to post new question but  getting error limit is cross.

Comment: give me brief explanation what you want then i will surely help